# Measuring sizes of before/after images in Photoshop

Tags: size, photoshop, resolution, image-resizing

Perhaps my mind isn't mathematically competent enough to do this, but here it goes:

I am using Photoshop.  I have 2 images taken from different heights.  Both images have the same object in it (so the size of this object remains the same) but I am trying to resize both images so that this object is the same pixel size.  That way I can properly measure the difference between other objects in the images with the proper ratio.

My end goal is to measure the differences of scars healing (before and after) using a same-size object in both images as a baseline.

To measure the difference in the photo, I have been counting pixels using the histogram feature:

[image: Look at different in pixels compared to the 2 even though they are the same]

Even though i changed the pixel width and height to roughly the same size, the 2 images have a drastically different number of pixels.  So comparing the red or white from the before to the after won't make sense until I can get these to match.

Can anyone point me in the right direction here?  How can I compare apples to apples here?

Answer (score 0):

So went a different route here in case anyone was trying wondering what I did.

Rather than change the size of the images, just calculated the increase manually separately.